# Expanding one player 'Snakes&Ladders' game to a multiplayer

Tags: r

Here is a code that simulates a game of Snakes and Ladders for one player:

```
    ladder.df <- data.frame(start=c(1,4,9,21,28,36,51,71,80), end=c(38,14,31,42,84,44,67,91,100))
slide.df <- data.frame(start=c(98,95,93,87,64,62,56,49,47,16), end=c(78,75,73,24,60,19,53,11,26,6))

curLoc <- 0 # Current location
nroll <- 0 # Number of rolls
slides <- 0 # Number of slides encountered
ladders <- 0 # Number of ladders encountered
# Keep rolling dice and moving until reach 100 or greater ending the game
while(curLoc < 100) {
  roll <- sample(6,1) # generate random number between [1 to 6]
  curLoc <- curLoc + roll # increase position
  nroll <- nroll + 1 # increase number of rolls
  # Need to check if we landed on a ladder or slide and move forward or back
  if (any(ladder.df$s %in% curLoc)) {
    curLoc <- ladder.df$e[ladder.df$s %in% curLoc]
    ladders <- ladders + 1
  }
  if (any(slide.df$s %in% curLoc)) {
    curLoc <- slide.df$e[slide.df$s %in% curLoc]
    slides <- slides + 1
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to expand it to a number of players where the user will specify this number. I have attempted to create a function and use a 'for' loop, however, failed to come up with the piece of code that updates global variables. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try a package I made called SnakesAndLaddersAnalysis (on CRAN). Aka install.packages("SnakesAndLaddersAnalysis")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about first putting your provided code into a function called `play_game()`:

```
play_game <- function(ladder_df, slide_df) {
  curLoc <- 0 # Current location
  nroll <- 0 # Number of rolls
  slides <- 0 # Number of slides encountered
  ladders <- 0 # Number of ladders encountered
  # Keep rolling dice and moving until reach 100 or greater ending the game
  while(curLoc < 100) {
    roll <- sample(6,1) # generate random number between [1 to 6]
    curLoc <- curLoc + roll # increase position
    nroll <- nroll + 1 # increase number of rolls
    # Need to check if we landed on a ladder or slide and move forward or back
    if (any(ladder_df$s %in% curLoc)) {
      curLoc <- ladder_df$e[ladder_df$s %in% curLoc]
      ladders <- ladders + 1
    }
    if (any(slide_df$s %in% curLoc)) {
      curLoc <- slide_df$e[slide_df$s %in% curLoc]
      slides <- slides + 1
    }
  }
  return(data.frame(  num_rolls = nroll,
                    num_ladders = ladders,
                     num_slides = slides))
}
```

This allows you to quickly play a game (with different "boards" -- i.e., different configurations of `ladder_df` and `slide_df`).

```
play_game(ladder.df, slide.df)
#   num_rolls num_ladders  num_slides 
# 1        23           2           3
```

Then you could extend this function to run with any number of players:

```
play_game_with_players <- function(num_players = 1, ladder_df, slide_df) {
  # Pre-allocate a list with the number of players
  results <- vector("list", num_players)
  for (i in seq_along(results)) {
    results[[i]] <- play_game(ladder_df, slide_df)
  }
  return(results)
}
```

At this point you can play with any number of players and they will be returned in `results[[i]]`. That is, `results[[2]]` represents the outcome for player 2.

```
play_game_with_players(num_players = 3, ladder.df, slide.df)
# [[1]]
# num_rolls num_ladders  num_slides 
#        14           3           0 
# 
# [[2]]
# num_rolls num_ladders  num_slides 
#         8           2           0 
# 
# [[3]]
# num_rolls num_ladders  num_slides 
#        67           4           7
```

Then you have flexibility in rolling up the results, such as binding all the rows together:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(play_game_with_players(num_players = 4, ladder.df, slide.df),
          .id = "player")
#   player num_rolls num_ladders num_slides
# 1      1        98           4         14
# 2      2        43           3          5
# 3      3        87           4         14
# 4      4        80           5         11
```

Update per comment: To simulate multiple games, you can use `replicate`. For example, let's simulate three, four-player, games:

```
sim_3 <- 
replicate(3, 
          bind_rows(play_game_with_players(num_players = 4, ladder.df, slide.df),
                    .id = 'player'), 
          simplify = FALSE)

bind_rows(sim_3, .id = "trial") %>% as_data_frame
# # A tibble: 12 x 5
#    trial player num_rolls num_ladders num_slides
#    <chr> <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
#  1 1     1           47.0        4.00       7.00
#  2 1     2           32.0        4.00       5.00
#  3 1     3           15.0        5.00       1.00
#  4 1     4           25.0        2.00       2.00
#  5 2     1           22.0        3.00       2.00
#  6 2     2           42.0        5.00       6.00
#  7 2     3           28.0        2.00       2.00
#  8 2     4           14.0        2.00       1.00
#  9 3     1           18.0        2.00       1.00
# 10 3     2           29.0        3.00       2.00
# 11 3     3           12.0        1.00       0   
# 12 3     4           46.0        4.00       5.00
```

At this point, you could do anything with that resulting table to summarize.

```
bind_rows(sim_3, .id = "trial") %>% 
  as_data_frame %>%
  group_by(player) %>%
  summarise(avg_rolls = mean(num_rolls),
            max_ladders = max(num_ladders))
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#    player avg_rolls max_ladders
#    <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#  1 1           29.0        4.00
#  2 2           34.3        5.00
#  3 3           18.3        5.00
#  4 4           28.3        4.00
```

Comment: That is great! Would you know by any chance how to repeat this function multiple times and collect the results for each player?(i.e. 2 players play a game 100 times etc.) I tried 'replicate()' and ''rep() functions but they do not work. Also, I tried to return vectors rather than data frame but no success there either